Maths Olympiad hints and/or solution about special number abcd
I thought I got the answer, but apparently not. I’d like some hints or maybe a solution to this question please (from HKMKC)
A special 4-digit number is $\overline{abcd}$. If $\overline{abcd} = a^a + b^b + c^c + d^d$, find the value of $a+b+c+d$.
I’m assuming the bar on top of abcd means that each letter is one number of the whole number, and also 6^6>10000, so the numbers can only be 1,2,3,4 or 5. I tried all of them into the equation, but nothing returned the same number. Anyway, the answer is 15 according the the mark scheme and my highest value is only 14, so I’m wondering if I misunderstood the question or something.
P.S. I’m not sure what tags to put
enter image description here

Discussion of past contest problems is often found at http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Forum/index.php?f=218

I don’t there’s much of my Olympiad on there because it’s relatively new and nothing came up even in google for any of the questions

Some casework-reducing measures:
Claim 1. The number must have exactly one $5$ in it.
Proof. Without a $5$, the highest we can hope for is $4^4+4^4+4^4+4^4 = 1024$. But this is less than $2000$, so actually we can hope for at most a $1$ in the first digit, for a better upper bound of $1^4 + 4^4 + 4^4 + 4^4 = 769$. But this is less than $1000$, so we don't get a $4$-digit number at all.
Two $5$'s are also too many, because $5^5 + 5^5 = 6250$, and the leading digit is too big.

Claim 2. The number must have two $3$'s and no $2$'s.
Proof. The divisibility rule by $9$ says that $\overline{abcd}$ and $a+b+c+d$ are congruent mod $9$, so if $\overline{abcd} = a^a + b^b + c^c + d^d$, then $a^a + b^b + c^c + d^d \equiv a + b + c + d \pmod 9$. In other words, $(a^a-a) + (b^b-b) + (c^c-c) + (d^d-d)$ is divisible by $9$. If we look at the quantity $x^x - x \bmod 9$ for $x=1, 2, 3, 4, 5$, then we get $0, 2, 6, 0, 6$, so we are choosing some combination of four $0$'s, $2$'s, and $6$'s to add up to a multiple of $9$. Because we know there is a $5$, we already have at least one $6$.
The only way to get divisibility by $3$ out of the $2$'s is $2+2+2$, but $2+2+2+6$ is not a multiple of $9$. So that rules out $2$ as a digit (because $x=2$ gives $x^x-x=2$).
To get divisibility by $9$ out of the $0$'s and $6$'s, we must either use no $6$'s or three of them. We get one $6$ from $5^5 - 5 \equiv 6 \pmod 9$, so we need two more from $3^3 - 3 \equiv 6 \pmod 9$. This completes the proof.

Now the digits can only be $1,3,3,5$ or $3, 3, 4, 5$ in some order. We have $1^1+3^3+3^3+5^5 = 3180$, which doesn't have $1,3,3,5$ as digits. But $3^3 + 3^3 + 4^4 + 5^5 = 3435$, whose digits happen to be $3, 4, 3, 5$.
Therefore $3435$ is the largest and only solution, and has $3+4+3+5=15$.
